# ajax how to read out $_post variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to filter/search a database with ajax

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "filterSearch.php",
   queryString: qry,
   success: function(data){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
     $('#searchResult').html(data); // Fill the search results box

   }
 });
```

Now in filterSearch.php i have the following test codes

```
if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
    echo "TEST";
}
if($_POST['runquery']==1) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM fs_vacatures WHERE here-the-like-query?";
$msg =  $sql;
echo $msg;
die();
}

die();
```

But nor TEST or the $sql is return in the alert??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.ajax` call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "filterSearch.php",
   data: {queryString: qry},
   success: function(data){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
     $('#searchResult').html(data); // Fill the search results box

   }
 });
```

That is, you will need to pass the parameter names and values using the [`data` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). In your example, you have invented a new option called `queryString` which just won't fly with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation about [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). There is **no** parameter `queryString`, **you have to use  `data`**.

It should look something like this then:

```
data: {'queryString': qry, 'runquery': 1}
```

---

**Update:**

Ok, either you use `POST` this way:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "filterSearch.php",
   data: {'runquery': 1, 'name': 'sdaf', 'asdf': 'asdf'}
   //...
 });
```

and then you have access to the parameters with `$_POST['runquery']`, `$_POST['name']`, etc.

Or you use `GET`:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "filterSearch.php" + qry, // which results in 'filterSearch.php?runquery=1&name=sdaf&asfd=asd'
   // ...
 });
```

and access the parameters via `$_GET['runquery']`, `$_GET['name']`, etc.

Comment: tx, to all i mixed up two things. $.post vs $.ajax and data: vs queryString: 

going to test it all

Comment: hmm, in qry i have ?runquery=1&name=sdaf&asfd=asdf

i thought filterSearch would read out runquery as a variable?

Comment: awesome thx

hmm i have another working solution, I removed the ? and now 
qry="runquery=1&name=asd&asfd=asdf";

type: "POST",
    url: "filterSearch.php",
    data: qry,
    success: function(msg){

and it seems to work nicely

Comment: @alex: Yes this should also work according to the documentation: *data: Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.* It is worth reading ;) Btw you should accept those answers that helped you the most for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery try to use "post" where you can add the post parameters as key-value-pairs:

```
$.post("filterSearch.php", { "queryString": "theValueOfQueryString", "runquery" : 1 },
   function(data){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
     $('#searchResult').html(data); // Fill the search results box
   });
```

see [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more Information

Answer (score 0):

I rather like the serialize method.

```
$.ajax({url: "filterSearch.php", type: "POST", data: $("form").serialize(), 
  success: function(data){

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.ajax(
  {
  type: "POST",
  url: "test.php",
  data: {'test': test, 'name': 0, 'asdf': 'asdf'},

    success: function(html)
    {
    alert(html);
    }
  });
```

and

```
<?php  
echo "come here";
echo $_POST['runquery'];
?>
```

dir

```
$ tree
.
├── a.php
└── test.php
```